# How to use Babel in Deno?

Tags: babeljs, deno

At the moment `deno bundle` does not support targeting older ES version such as ES3, since it's by default targeting ESNext, it makes the bundled code unable to be executed in certain environments.

Therefore, I wanted to use Babel to transpile the bundled code to a more compatible version ES.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by importing Babel standalone from `jspm.io`.

```
import babelstandalone from "https://dev.jspm.io/@babel/standalone"

const code = `var x = 5`
const transformed = babelstandalone.transform(code, { 
  presets: ['env'] 
}).code
console.log(transformed)
```

If you intended to run the `transformed` code in browser, you will need to import `runtime.js`. You can do so by including the following script tag in your HTML file.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/regenerator-runtime@0.13.1/runtime.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is this still the best way to do this?

Comment: @Daniel I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.28, Deno supports importing NPM packages via NPM specifiers. You can find this in [the docs](https://deno.land/manual@v1.32.3/node/npm_specifiers). To use NPM specifiers you import the dependency like you would in Node.js using require, except you prefix the name with `npm:`.

To import Babel utilities, you can use the following code:

```
import { parse } from 'npm:@babel/parser';
import _traverse from 'npm:@babel/traverse';
import * as types from 'npm:@babel/types';

const traverse = _traverse.default;
```

Notice how `traverse` is assigned `_traverse.default`. Trying to import `traverse` and use it directly will throw an error telling you that `traverse` is not a function.

CDNs like [ESM](https://esm.sh), [UNPKG](https://unpkg.com), and [JSPM](https://jspm.io/) [can be used](https://deno.land/manual@v1.32.3/node/cdns) as alternatives. However, I ran into the following error when trying to use the babel utilities via [ESM](https://esm.sh):

```bash
error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statement')
    at https://esm.sh/v114/@babel/helper-function-name@7.21.0/deno/helper-function-name.mjs:2:1566
    at https://esm.sh/v114/@babel/helper-function-name@7.21.0/deno/helper-function-name.mjs:2:650
    at https://esm.sh/v114/@babel/helper-function-name@7.21.0/deno/helper-function-name.mjs:26:147
```

As you can see, the error occurred in the dependency and not in my code. I didn't try out the other CDNs. The NPM specifiers worked like a charm.